# Woocommerce show more variables in admin area

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In Woocommerce within the product edit screen, under variables, I currently have products which have up to 52 options, this is displayed over 4 pages, however I need to increase the number so that I can see all 52 in one page, as I need to move the variable order around but can't move from page to page

There is something in Woocommmerce telling it too only show 20 and pagination, so there must be a way to increase this number

Comment: You mean the product attributes
http://prntscr.com/gfgrsw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you want to change the number of variations shown per page in the edit screen.
Please add the following code in your functions.php

```
function update_variations_number(){
  return 100; //change your desired number
}
add_filter('woocommerce_admin_meta_boxes_variations_per_page', 'update_variations_number');
```

Comment: You sir are a life saver!! I couldn't find anything on the web to tell me what to do!!

Comment: @user3593556 glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also double click on the drag icon and manually set the order that way.